# Flutter: Detect and Display Available eSIMs on a Phone

Tags: flutter, dart, sim-card, e-sim

I am able to detect and display the physical SIM cards present in the phone, and I can initiate a call with the SIM chosen by my user without the system doing it for them. To achieve this, I use the [simnumber](https://pub.dev/packages/simnumber) package. My current challenge is how to also detect and display eSIMs (if there are any)?

An eSIM (embedded Subscriber Identity Module) is a digital SIM card that is embedded within a device and can be remotely programmed with mobile network credentials, eliminating the need for a physical SIM card.

I have already tried several packages that enable the detection of available SIM cards in the phone. However, they do not assist me in detecting and displaying the available eSIMs in the phone. I would like to know if there is a method to accomplish this.